# matlab normalizing codes algorithm

Tags: matlab

The below is a matlab code for normalizing the data. Can somebody please explain the algorithm behind? I am very new to matlab and I want to understand the logic behind. It looks complicated to me.

T is a data matrix

```
G = [min(T,[],1);max(T,[],1)]
h = bsxfun(@minus,T,G(1,:));
h = bsxfun(@rdivide,h,diff(G,1,1))
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a perfect example of a very short, but not readable matlab code.

In the first line you are creating the variable B, which is an array with just two inputs. The first input is the minimum of the variable T in it's first dimension. (An example for dimensions can you see if you are loading an image. The first dimension is the width, the second the height and the last will be the color channels R, G, B). The second input is the maximum of the variable T, also in it's first dimension. (See min doku of matlab here: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html)

The second line applies and element-wise operation (the minus operation) on T and your variable G. But of G, you are taking just the first ROW, with all it's elements inside. Element wise means you are taking T(1)-G(1) till T(n)-G(n).

In the third line, you are again applying an element wise operation with rdivide (See the official matlab docu about rdivide here: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) of the h variable (defined before) and the difference of G and 1 in the first dimension.

`diff(G,1,1)`: calculates the nth difference of G in the first dimension (https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html). So if you have an vector like (1,2,3,4) it would calculate 2-1, 3-2, 4-3 --> (1,1,1)

`rdivide(h, diff(G,1,1))` is an other way of writing: A./B . And that means you divide every element of B, by the corresponding element of A. For example:
A = (12, 21, 16) and B = (2, 3, 4) your result would be (12/2, 21/3, 16/4) --> (6, 7, 4)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is so clear. Now I understand it. The T is actually my matrix and when I ran it, it generated a matrix with elements between 0 and 1. So is it good if the above code was used? Hence this is why I wanted to figure out how the code worked and was scared that the output didn't make any sense.

Comment: It is some kind of art to write short code, especially in Matlab. That's because when it is short, normally it will run faster. So add some comments and help the next reader by this to understand what this part is doing and it should be fine.